# How to automatically resize columns in C1flexGrid?

Tags: c#, c1flexgrid

If I choose one of the WF which have C1flexGrid, and try to maximize that form, columns in my grid have the same width.  What I am trying to do is have the columns auto fit to the width of the content, and have the last column fill the remaining space. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for the answer:
You can use AutoSizeCols method and ExtendLastCol property

```
c1FlexGrid1.ExtendLastCol = true;    
c1FlexGrid1.AutoSizeCols(c1FlexGrid1.Cols.Fixed, c1FlexGrid1.Cols.Count - 1)
```

[Reference](http://help.grapecity.com/componentone/NetHelp/c1flexgrid/webframe.html#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid~AutoSizeCols.html).